# Проблема с версткой видеоплеера HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5, видео

Здравствуйте! Верстаю себе видео плеер на сайт:

Видом доволен, функционалом в принципе доволен, но есть нюансы. И тут у меня сразу 2 вопроса:

1) Слайдер звука не запоминает позицию пользователя.

2) Не получается сделать выход из fullscreen. Код для выхода из полноэкранного режима находится в функции `exitFullScreen*()`

Спасибо заранее за любую помощь.

Вот скрипты:

```js
var vid, muteButton, volumeSlider, fullScreenToggler, fullscreenHider;

function intializePlayer(){
"use strict"; 
// Set object references 

muteButton = document.getElementById("muteUnmute");
volumeSlider = document.getElementById("volumeSlider");
fullScreenToggler = document.getElementById("toggleFullScreen");
fullscreenHider = document.getElementById("exitFullScreen");
// Add event listeners

muteButton.addEventListener("click",muteUnmute,false);
volumeSlider.addEventListener("input",volumeChange,false);
fullScreenToggler.addEventListener("click",enterFullScreen,false);
fullscreenHider.addEventListener("click",exitFullScreen,false); 
}

window.onload = intializePlayer;

function volumeChange(){
"use strict";
 vid.volume = volumeSlider.value / 100;
}
function enterFullScreen(){
"use strict";
 if(vid.requestFullScreen){
  vid.requestFullScreen();}
 else if(vid.webkitRequestFullScreen){
  vid.webkitRequestFullScreen();}
 else if(vid.mozRequestFullScreen){
  vid.mozRequestFullScreen();}
 else if(vid.oRequestFullScreen){
  vid.oRequestFullScreen();}
 else if(vid.msRequestFullScreen){
  vid.msRequestFullScreen();}
 document.getElementsByClassName("videoControls")[0].classList.add("fullscreen"); 
    fullScreenToggler.style.display = "none";
 fullscreenHider.style.display = "inline-block";
 }
function exitFullScreen(){
"use strict"; 
 if(vid.cancelFullScreen){
  vid.cancelFullScreen();}
 else if(vid.webkitCancelFullScreen){
  vid.webkitCancelFullScreen();}
 else if(vid.mozCancelFullScreen){
  vid.mozCancelFullScreen();}
 else if(vid.oCancelFullScreen){
  vid.oCancelFullScreen();}
 else if(vid.msCancelFullScreenn){
  vid.msCancelFullScreen();}
    document.getElementsByClassName("videoControls")[0].classList.remove("fullscreen"); 
    fullscreenHider.style.display = "none";
 fullScreenToggler.style.display = "inline-block"; 
}

function muteUnmute(){
"use strict";
 if(vid.volume >= 0.03){
  volumeSlider.value = 0;
  vid.volume = 0;
  toggleIcon();
 }
    else if(vid.volume <= 0.05){
  volumeSlider.value = 100;
  vid.volume = volumeSlider.value / 100;
  toggleIcon();
 }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не очень интересный, вот и нет ответов, тем более, что в вопросе куча кода, который надо умозрительно отладить, чтобы дать ответ.
Впрочем, ответы содержатся в самом вопросе.
1. Функция Mute не запоминает последнее положение слайдера. Смотрим в код - действительно, оно никак вроде ей не передается.
2. Функция выхода из полноэкранного режима. "Вроде все правильно написал, но не работает" - значит, слово "вроде" тут не подходит, надо отладить - понять, почему не срабатывает - и написать верно.

Comment: @labris Ок, так норм?

Comment: Если бы Вы спросили как сделать фулскрин или как написать кнопку, то получилы бы ответ. Но Вы просите переписать за Вас программу в сотню строк кода, которую читать легко наверное только Вам.

Comment: @labris Да, вы правы, но я больше о**ел (сорри за это) когда увидел: "Из текста удалено 10712 символов" o_O O_o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Запомните уровень звука, когда ставите mute и ставьте его, а не 100% когда убираете

```
var prev_level;

function muteUnmute(){
"use strict";
    if(vid.volume >= 0.03){
        prev_level=volumeSlider.value
        volumeSlider.value = 0;
        ...
    }
    else if(vid.volume <= 0.05){
        volumeSlider.value = prev_level;
        ...
    }
}
```

2)`cancelFullScreen` относится ко всему документу, а не к элементу. Он вызывается через `document`:

```
    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    document.oCancelFullScreen();
    document.msCancelFullScreen();
```